# Change CSS on every click of a button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I want to increase the right margin of *.questionarea* by 400px every time a user clicks on *.go*. Here's my Javascript.

```
            var marright = "-400px"
        $(".go").click(function(){
          $(".questionarea").animate({
            marginRight: marright
          }, 300 );
         marright += "-400px";
        });
```

If you take out the second last line, the button works once but I've got no idea of the syntax for increasing the size of the margin on each additional click.

Comment: You are appending "-400px" each time. So `marright` is becoming something like "-400px-400px-400px-400px" (A string). Add the "px" after the arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var marright = -400;
$(".go").click(function(){
    $(".questionarea").animate({
        marginRight: marright
    }, 300, function(){
        marright += -400;
    });
});
```

You don't need to have `marright` as a string with the `px` on the end of it. Jquery is clever enough to work that out for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(".go").click(function(){
      $(".questionarea").animate({
        marginRight: "-=400"
      }, 300 );
    });
```

I think it should be like this.